# Flutter doctor is not running in command prompt

Tags: flutter

I have been using flutter smoothly before this but suddenly when I run flutter doctor in my command prompt I get the following error.

> Updating flutter tool...
>   Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Users\personal\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\linter-0.1.43".
>   Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...

I have also uninstalled the flutter and dart plugin from the android studio but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you 'Retried in five seconds'

Comment: Yes that i tried to do in the first place

Comment: It's probably a network problem. Are you in China or nehind anpther firewall.

Comment: No I am not from china. My network is also working fine

Comment: If its still cannot solve. You can file a bug here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will keep that for future but I solved my problem and I have given the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the cache folder in the following location.

> C:\Users\personal\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\

Now my flutter doctor is working again.